# error from spring when run java application

Tags: java, spring

I tried to run java application and I got error

```
39e50b6c8500","container_id":"10.0.137.104","type":"log","logger":"org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader","thread":"localhost-startStop-1","level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"Context initialization failed","stacktrace":["org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'resourceServerFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#54de2a69' of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager] while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#54de2a69': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'offlineTokenServices' while setting bean property 'tokenServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'offlineTokenServices' is defined","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)","at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)","at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)","at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)","at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)","at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)","at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)","at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)","at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)","at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)","at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)","at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)","at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)","at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)","at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:808)","Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'resourceServerFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#54de2a69' of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager] while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#54de2a69': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'offlineTokenServices' while setting bean property 'tokenServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'offlineTokenServices' is defined","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:632)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1115)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)"] }
{ "written_at":"2017-08-24T07:21:18.874Z","written_ts":1261972550043975,"component_type":"application","component_id":"e3b133e6-4a3b-4f39-ae1e-cde2bc778e64","space_name":"automation","component_name":"I053322-fg00k8se6s2ce433-mtaTest-java","component_instance":"0","organization_id":"-","correlation_id":"-","organization_name":"-","space_id":"01769eda-4790-45e8-9333-39e50b6c8500","container_id":"10.0.137.104","type":"log","logger":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/]","thread":"localhost-startStop-1","level":"ERROR","categories":[],"msg":"Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]","stacktrace":["org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'resourceServerFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#54de2a69' of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager] while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#54de2a69': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'offlineTokenServices' while setting bean property 'tokenServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'offlineTokenServices' is defined","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1457)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)","at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)","at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)","at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)","at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)","at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)","at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)","at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)","at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)","at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)","at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)","at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)","at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)","at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)","at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:808)","Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'resourceServerFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceServerFilter': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#54de2a69' of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager] while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#54de2a69': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'offlineTokenServices' while setting bean property 'tokenServices'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'offlineTokenServices' is defined","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:632)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1115)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)","at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)"] }
```

This is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <servlet id="Servlet_1487837886290">
        <servlet-name>ODataServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.cloud.oataServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping id="ServletMapping_1487837886286">
        <servlet-name>ODataServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/odata/v4/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>package</param-name>
        <param-value>com.company.extension.java</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.service.prov.v4.web.ServiceInitializer</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

I added the file spring-security.xml in WEB-INF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
   xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

   <!-- protect secure resource endpoints ================================================ -->

   <sec:http pattern="/**" create-session="never"
      entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
      authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
      use-expressions="true">
      <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />

      <!-- section to protect your endpoints -->

      <!-- Example: Check a specific OAuth Scope (i.e., authorization) on a resource -->
      <!-- sec:intercept-url pattern="/odata/v4/CustomerService/**" access="isAuthenticated()" method="GET" /-->
      <!-- sec:intercept-url pattern="/odata/v4/CustomerService/ProposedCustomers/**" access="#oauth2.hasScope('${xs.appname}.Approve')" method="PUT" /-->
      <!-- Example: Check only authentication on a resource -->
      <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

      <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
      <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
   </sec:http>

   <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
   </bean>

   <bean id="oauthWebExpressionHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler">
   </bean>

   <bean id="accessDecisionManager"
      class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
      <constructor-arg>
         <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter">
               <property name="expressionHandler" ref="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"  />
         </list>
      </constructor-arg>
   </bean>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"/>

   <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
      resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="offlineTokenServices" />



   <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

   <!-- define properties file =========================================================== -->
   <bean class="com.sap.xs2.security.commons.SAPPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="location"  value="classpath:/application.properties" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

No `offlineTokenServices` bean is found. You referenced

```
<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
  resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="offlineTokenServices" />
```

But no definition of the offlineTokenServices

Comment: sorry I am new in spring . what do I need to fix or remove ?

Comment: You need to define the bean or reference existing bean. I don't know the logic you are trying to implement. In fact you need token service and you referenced to not existing one.